# Justify-Content Flexbox working different in Chrome vs Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, webkit, flexbox

I put it up on Codepen so you can take a look
Specifically this segment is what I've been trying to work with

```
input[type="radio"]:checked.book + div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Entire thing: http://codepen.io/Trel/pen/JRBvLv

Essentially what's happening is I'm trying to use `justify-content` to center those lines of text.

What's happening is in Firefox, it's looking how I expected it to.
In Chrome, it's stretching further and overflowing it's container.

I'm not sure which is doing it right, but Firefox is showing the behavior I was aiming for.

Comment: Try removing the <br /> tag and use padding or margin instead

Comment: The problem seems to be how the browsers interpret the `br` tag itself and it inside the flexbox ... removing that first br tag solves the issue

Comment: If I remove the <br /> is it forcing the line break between ungrouped items due to the flexbox + flex direction? If so that would work for my goal here.